# Getting ALL of element's children?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to return all of an elements "offspring", including the children of its children?

I'm sure there is an easy way, but all I can think of is recursion with `.children`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `getElementsByTagName` and pass "*" as the argument, for example:

```
var oDiv = document.getElementById("MyDiv");
var allChildrenDeep = oDiv.getElementsByTagName("*");
```

Note though that for top level element with many sub elements, it can reach hundreds of items in that array, so keep an eye over the efficiency.

Comment: I thought you could only use the "getElement" methods on the document object?

Comment: Not at all. You can use all methods on any DOM element.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - _almost_ all: `getElementById()` is the exception. (Not that it would make sense to use it at any other level given that Id is supposed to be unique.)

Comment: @nnn thanks, didn't know that and never got chance to try it.. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
element.getElementsByTagName('*');
```

Will return a live list of all elements that are further down the tree than `element`. Example Usage:

```
function getSubtreeBelowElementById(id){
    return document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName('*');
}
```

Note that this will only return HTML Nodes, it will skip over Comment nodes and Text nodes.

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting vaguely new browsers, then you could use `querySelectorAll`

```
var c = document.getElementById('myElement');
var offspring = c.querySelectorAll('*');
```

*Edit: **Don't use this method.** The browser support is not as ubiquitous as `getElementsByTagName` and it is not optimised as much. Quick benchmarking showed it to be about 5x slower.*